# my vscode run super slow . what should I do

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

my "hello world" program in python and C/C++ take about 7 seconds to run . what should i do

```
python
print("Hello world!")
```

and

```
C++
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "run" or "compile then run" or "run in debug mode" ?

Comment: and check if your antivirus scans newly compiled programs. It's one of the notorious reasons for slow startup time

Comment: @SteveB I run it with "run code" and "run python file"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is a `program in python and C/C++ `?

Comment: @VladFeinstein I mean i have ran a "hello world" program written in  python and another "hello world " program written with C/C++ and it both taken a long time to run

Comment: Well, C/C++ must be compiled and linked - that might take some time. For Python, please post the entire file content.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I've just upload my code in python and c++. Also, I ran my C++ code in codeblock and dev-C++ and it ran faster (5 seconds)

Comment: I can only confirm (as expected) that running that Python file take no measurable time at all. See how long it will take you to run this commend: `python --version`

Comment: It took 5 seconds , sir